# Какой лучше способ для создания web чата

Tags: php, чат

Поделитесь пожалуйста опытом создания чата на PHP или javascript.
Вчера целый день потратил на изучение WebSocket, даже взял в аренду VDS, подключил этот dll или как его назвать не знаю. Установил на него готовые скрипты чата на PHP/WbSocket и ни один не заработал. Просто потратил 1 день и деньги.

Был опыт в создании чата на PHP/Mysql но из-за частых запросов в базу, хостинг временно отключает доступ. Значит уже отпадает.

Думал реализовать на файлах или на sqlite3, но не знаю какая будет загрузка на сервер, если например человек 100 будет в чате и от каждого будут идти запросы например 1 раз в 5(10) сек. Где можно посмотреть или кто знает плохо это или совсем ужасно?

Если мне кто-нибудь поможет разобраться почему не работает чат на WebSocket у меня, буду очень благодарен.

Comment: Мне кажется, что выбор php для реализации чата - не очень удачная идея. Это как раз очень слабая ниша php.

Answer (score 1):

Если хотите чат на *php*, тогда используйте `LongPoll`. В интернете кстати есть очень много примеров реализации.

Но если Вам нужно на `WebSocket`, тогда используйте *node.js*.

Есть много уже готовых библиотек для реализации, например http://socket.io/

Comment: А node.js обязательно использовать к socket.io ? Или можно на jquery сделать? И ещё вопрос: если WebSocket нет на хостинге, то socket.io будет работать?

Comment: Есть много других реализаций WebSocket на node.js